# php mysql count() returns 1 ! no counting in DB

Tags: php, mysql

I did search for answer before I posted :) !

Now my problem is php mysql script have to count records in mysql database cells I will try to draw my db now

table name: tableurl (table contains two columns url and clicks)

```
----------------
 url      clicks
clhgfghfh    6
hgjhgjhgh    0
kjhgjhgjh    0
khgjhgjhg    1
asdasddsg    5
-----------------
```

Now I want to count all the clicks so output should be 12 ! here is my code

```
<?php
/* db connection included in head*/

$sql ="SELECT count(clicks) FROM tableurl";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {  
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("Clicks together %d \n",$rowcount);
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
?>
```

P.S. clicks in db is defined as INT 
lenght/value is 1
default is NULL

Any input what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: `mysqli_num_rows` counts the rows returned from the db, so it correctly says `1`

Answer (score 3):

You want to sum the clicks and not count the number of records in your table. Use `SUM()`

```
SELECT sum(clicks) as click_sum 
FROM tableurl
```

and then use something like

```
if($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $sum = $row["click_sum"];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$sql ="SELECT SUM(clicks) as totalClicks FROM tableurl";
if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {  
  $res = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  printf("Clicks together %d \n",$res['totalClicks']);
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }
```

Comment: thank you for reply's

I manageg to put together code and it works now thank you juergen d and thank you sgt !

code for anyone in same trouble.

<?php
/* Gets all click's */
$query = "SELECT SUM(clicks) As clickstogether FROM tableurl";                
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $median = $row['clickstogether'];
    echo $row['clickstogether'];
?>

Anyone can fix my comment ?